# Cors issue when deploying a mernstack app on minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cors, devops, minikube

I have a mern stack app (react vite + nodejs) web app that is working fine as i enabled cors middleware to allow my frontend to send requests to the backend but the problem is when i tried to deploy that stack on minikube(deployment-frontend + deployment-backend) i got the cross origin error although it is configured properly in my source code and work well without deployment .
I don't know what's the cause of the problem , even when i used docker compose to test the dockerfiles and the whole stack it went well but the problem occurs in minikube .

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend
        image: achref2h/frontend:v2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: achref2h/backend:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

Frontend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20 as builder

WORKDIR /frontend

COPY  package*.json ./

RUN npm i

COPY  . . 

RUN npm run build

FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install nginx -y

COPY --from=builder /frontend/dist /var/www/html/

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

Backend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts AS builder

WORKDIR /api 

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY  . ./

RUN npm run build

FROM node:lts-slim

WORKDIR /api 

COPY --from=builder /api/ ./

RUN npm install --only=production

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "./dist/index.js"]
```

note :

- For testing purposes this is a simple mern app that does not need database just frontend send two simple requests to backend
- frontend hosted within nginx on port 80 and backend is running on port 3000 .
  thanks in advance !

Comment: Definitely not on-topic here, but CORS issues are fixed (in this case since you wrote the server code) by including appropriate CORS middleware on your server - `although it is configured properly in my source code` - we have only your word on that